# UIPageViewController + Static Buttons

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipageviewcontroller

1. My UIPageViewController displays a full size images. Below the image, appears a white bar (in the same space where the dots of PageControl appears), how can i clear that white bar and leave the dots?
2. In addition, i´ve created a button but when i swipe the screen, the button swipe as well. How can i leave the button static in the window?

Thanks in advance ¡¡

Answer (score 0):

To prevent button from swiping make a top view of your page controller.
To remove white bar make an IBOutlet to your view and set color to

```
[UIColor clearColor]
```

Comment: i´m using the next code: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/        but when i add [UIColor clearColor] the white bar remains above the image. What else can i do for make the bar translucent? .